# Online statistics course using python for teaching

Tags: probability, statistics, online-resources

I am interested in data science and data analysis. I have been reading been reading on self-study but when it comes to statistics, I feel I need a course from an expert to help me grasp some of the statistics concepts and particularly when using python to analyse them. can someone point me to a statistics course on edx or coursera, or even anywhere, that uses python? I keep seeing R and know nothing about R during my search.

Comment: Google is your friend here. I found [this](https://www.coursera.org/specializations/statistics-with-python) on coursera after a quick google search.

Comment: There's [this](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-statistics-with-python) course on codeacademy as well, but I think you have to pay for that.

Comment: This [site](https://github.com/unpingco/Python-for-Probability-Statistics-and-Machine-Learning-2E/) has a Python statistics section and corresponding [book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783030185442)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's best (that's how I did it) to learn the concepts and then try to translate it to Python yourself. So then you would need two resources: a good resource to learn the statistical concepts step by step ánd a good resource to translate it to Python from scratch.

These are the two resources I advise respectively:

1. The youtube channel 'StatQuest' by Josh Starmer.
2. The site by Jason Brownlee on how to build algorithms from scratch (focused on statistical concepts for machine learning): https://machinelearningmastery.com/

You can find so many courses online covering Python and data science, so you can't expect a complete answer to your question (I also think your question belongs more to the cross validated page or something similar). I suggest you browse down the web and look at several options. I did this as well and these two resources hereabove, gave me the highest increase in knowledge. So it doesn't mean these are the only two you need!